# When sending an HttpRequestMessage via HTTPClient, what is the best way of knowing that the request reached the target destination?

Tags: c#

When sending an `HttpRequestMessage` via `HTTPClient` and an exception is caught, I want to know if the request reached the destination. Because if not, I may want to retry sending the message.

Currently, I'm looking at the `HTTPRequestException` caught and the `HttpRequestException.StatusCode`, which is sometimes empty. An example of that happening is when the destination system would restart in the middle of processing the request. I'm seeing an inner `SocketException` and I would look at the `SocketException.SocketErrorCodes` too.

Is this a better way of doing this?

Comment: You may want to look into the Polly library, which solves exactly this.

Comment: The only way is to use a timeout when you do not get a response with status code.  TLS can fail, the server can be off-line, there may not be a route to the IP, or the port is blocked.  All of these will fail with no response.  Plus other reasons.

Comment: _"best way of **knowing that the request reached the target destination**?"_ - The _only_ way of **knowing** that the request reached the destination is when you receive the response. Now, the response may be an error response, but it still means, the request reached the destination. _In all other cases_ you must assume it didn't. That includes that you may _never_ get a response, in which case you need a timeout (which is set by default in most frameworks / network stacks). To fortify, [Polly](https://www.thepollyproject.org/) already has been suggested, which I second.